# Vue-js event after full rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling

Vue-js I have been trying to use a simple javascript onload event that moves the page down to a particular row in a table. Those rows are separate components, each with its own id. Something like this:

```
mounted: function () {
    this.getExcList(); // load data for exceptions from server
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        location.hash = "exc_"+this.excn0;
    });
},
```

It works fine if you run it once the page is loaded, but apparently the mounted event is just too early. In this case, the data for loading (this.getExcList) only arrives then.
Is there a simple answer to this question: How do you run an onload event in Vue-js, that only happens after the render is complete?
There are so many questions online about things like this. Surely there is a standard answer? Thanks!

- Update, based on comments:
  Trying this

```
  async created () { // backend to get data on exceptions
    await this.getExcList(this.archiveyear); // load data for exceptions
  },  
  mounted: function () { 
        
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        location.hash = "exc_"+this.excn0;
    });
     
  },
```

It still doesn't jump to the location.

Comment: Depends how and what is being mounted. Some things have a "I'm done loading" event emitted, so this can help. But `nextTick` is usually a nice way to go indeed.

Comment: `mounted` does executed after the first render of the component. Are you loading the table data asynchronously? If so, then it's your job to coordinate the timing of such events.

Comment: You should run `await this.getExcList()` in `async created()`.

Comment: @DecadeMoon I am not loading the table data asynchronously, but it does happen in the mounted event itself [added to question].

Comment: @kissu Thank you - could you explain that a little more?

Comment: `created()` is meant to be the lifecycle where you run any kind of HTTP calls etc. On top of that, if you just run `this.getExcList()` in your `mounted` without waiting for it to be done (thanks to `await`), it will basically not wait until the HTTP call is done and enter the `nextTick` block since JS is async by default.

Comment: @kissu See updated post.